# Сколько максимально одновременных подключений может держать сервер?

Tags: сеть

В стать https://habrahabr.ru/post/50028/ говориться что были сервера способные держать 1 000 000 пользователей. А как такое возможно если портов всего 2^16?

Comment: К одному порту, принимающему соединения, может подключаться сколько угодно клиентов

Comment: А как такое сделать? Ведь accept создаёт новый сокет с новым портом постоянно.

Comment: accept не создаёт никаких портов

Comment: "accept создаёт новый сокет с новым портом".- Другими словами новый сокет привязанный к другому порту.

Comment: Это вы где-то каких-то глупостей начитались. Accept принимает входящее соединение и создаёт для него новый сокет. Но никаких новых портов он не создаёт! За этим сокетом закреплены IP и порт, но оба они идентифицируют клиента, а не принадлежат серверу — это клиент у себя создаёт порт. На сервере никаких портов не создаётся.

Comment: Если знаете как работает то дайте развёрнутый полный ответ с примерами, а не некойте тут в комментах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Соединение характеризуется следующей конструкцией из 5 элементов:

```
IP клиента, Порт клиента, IP сервера, Порт сервера, Протокол
```

Например:

```
10.0.0.1:1234 192.168.0.1:80 TCP
10.0.0.1:1235 192.168.0.1:80 TCP
10.0.0.1:1236 192.168.0.1:80 TCP
...
10.0.0.2:1234 192.168.0.1:80 TCP
10.0.0.2:1235 192.168.0.1:80 TCP
10.0.0.2:1236 192.168.0.1:80 TCP
...
```

Последние 3 элемента имеют фиксированное значение, а вот первые 2 изменяются и в комбинации могут давать огромные значения. С одного IP может подключиться до 64k клиентов, с другого ещё столько же и т.д. Таким образом, теоретическое максимальное число соединений может быть равно `число клиентских IP адресов * число портов на клиенте (64k)`.

С практической же точки зрения, ресурсы сервера (RAM, CPU, I/O) ограничены, и в зависимости от реализации сервера, он может обрабатывать лишь какое-то N-ное число одновременных соединений, которое меньше теоретического `IP*64k`.

Чем эффективнее написан сервер (т.е. чем эффективнее он использует ограниченные ресурсы железа), тем больше соединений он сможет держать. Самые неэффективные реализации создают по процессу на каждое входящее соединение, более эффективные используют один процесс и создают по потоку (thread) на соединение, а ещё более эффективные умеют обходиться фиксированным числом процессов и потоков, выполняя асинхронную обработку запросов.

Answer (score 1):

Порты не имеют никакого отношения к одновременному колличеству подключений. Порт - это просто место, куда приходит запрос\подключение. 
Что именно обработает запрос на этот порт - вот это уже важно. И там говорится не про сервера, а про функциональный язык программирования `Erlang`, на котором можно написать проект, максимально задействующий ресурсы машины, что в свою очередь может дать до миллиона одновременных коннектов.
Итак, ответ на ваш вопрос - дело вообще не в портах.

Comment: Только надо было дописать, что виртуальная среда Erlang автоматически балансирует обработчики между всеми доступными машинами в кластере. А на одной машине (всё-таки) -- максимум 64к сокетов, а операционная система их режет ещё сильнее.